# How to create stacked bar chart using google charts using php and mysql?

Tags: php

I want to design a 100% stacked bar chart using **PHP** and **mySQL**. But I'm unable to pass the data to the array to DataTable. I was able to get JSON encoded data, but couldn't pass it to the chart.

Please provide a solution

Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?Gcharts/stackchart",
    dataType : "JSON",
    success : function(result) {
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages' : [ 'corechart' ]
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            drawStacked(result);
        });
    }
});

google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);
var dataArray=[];
function drawStacked(result) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
            var dataArray = [];
            $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
                dataArray.push([ obj.name, parseInt(obj.quantity) ]);
            });

            data.addRows(dataArray)
        /* I want my json data to be inserted as shown below*/
        /*['GOLD', 10, 0,24, 0,0,20, 0,32, 0,0,0,18, 5, ''],
        ['IPHONE', 16, 0,0,22,0,0,0, 23, 0,0,30, 16, 9, ''],
        ['TOMATOES', 0,0,28, 0,19, 0,0,0,29, 0, 30, 12, 13, ''],
        ['ALL COLORS', 10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,'']*/


        var options = {
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 5 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: 'percent',
        hAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            ticks: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
          },
    series: {
    0:{color:'#00FF00'},
    1:{color:'#40FF00'},
    2:{color:'#80FF00'},
    3:{color:'#C0FF00'},
    4:{color:'#FFFF00'},
    5:{color:'#FFC000'},
    6:{color:'#FF8000'},
    7:{color:'#FF4000'},
    8:{color:'#FF0000'},
    9:{color:'#E00000'},
    10:{color:'#A00000'},
    11:{color:'#800000'},
    12:{color:'#E0E0E0'},
    }
      };



      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('status_bar_diagram'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }


});

</script>
```

I'm trying to print stacked bar graph using dynamic data,where y axis is product name(Gold) and along x axis ,i want to show purchase orders stacked on.

Comment: Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52365458/edit) your question and add the relevant source code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can code as below :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Stack Graph</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
      </script>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});     
      </script>
   </head>       
   <body>
      <div id = "container" style = "width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
      </div>
      <script language = "JavaScript">
         function drawChart() {
            // You can define your data OR json
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['Year', 'Asia', 'Europe'],
                  ['2012',  50,      390],
                  ['2013',  100,      400],
                  ['2014',  150,      440],
                  ['2015',  250,       480],
                  ['2016',  330,      540]
             ]);

            var options = {
                isStacked: 'percent',
                height: 300,
                legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 3},
                hAxis: {
                  minValue: 0,
                  ticks: [0, .3, .6, .9, 1]
                }
              };

            // Instantiate and draw the chart.
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('container'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
         }
         google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please show me how to get json data in arrayToDataTable

Comment: You can prepare data by loop as required format in arrayToDataTable in your code and then use it in script.